# c++ Observer Pattern: raw pointers vs shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr, observer-pattern

I'm in the process of converting (at least) some of my code to using shared_ptr.  However I'm running into an issue with the Observer pattern which I'm using.

I have a presenter class (Model View Presenter) which implements the Observer pattern and it gets notified when certain events happens.  I wrote generic Subject/Observer classes that any class can inherit from.  The update method looks something like this:

```
void MyPresenter::Update(Subject *subject)
{
    if(subject == myService_)
    {
        DoSomething();
    }
    else if(subject == myOtherService_)
    {
        DoSomethingElse();
    }

}
```

This worked fine until I converted `myService_` (a member of MyPresenter class) to a `std::shared_ptr`.  Now the expression `(subject == myService_)` is no longer valid.

I may eventually convert everything to shared_ptr, but until then is there an easy way for me to support both raw pointers and shared_ptr's with the Observer pattern?  Ideally I'd like the observer pattern to be agnostic to the observer's pointer implementation but maybe that's not possible.  How can I fix this?

**UPDATE**

Should an observer pattern Observer interface take a shared pointer?  Or is it better to keep it as raw pointers?  Currently I have:

```
class Subject;

class Observer
{
public:
    virtual ~Observer() {}
    virtual void Update(Subject *subject) = 0;

protected:
    Observer() {}
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `shared_ptr`'s get member, which returns the raw pointer that the `shared_ptr` wraps:

```
subject == myService_.get()
```

In general I would not suggest to blindly convert all raw pointers to `shared_ptr`s. You always have to think about if the surrounding object really owns the pointed by object (and shared ownership is still ownership). Sometimes a `std::unique_ptr` (although I don't know if `tr1` already has that, otherwise a `std::auto_ptr`) is a better choice, if it is strict ownership or also just a raw pointer, if it is no ownership.

But in interfaces, especially function arguments and return values, raw pointers are often a better idea than using smart pointers and thus decreasing genericity (and also performance, though only insignificantly, but even more so for `shared_ptr`'s).

**NOTE:** I know this is the same answer as the already existing one, but I desperately felt the need against just suggesting to use `shared_ptr`s all over the place.

Comment: Using Visual Studio 2010 and I just found I can use `std::shared_ptr` instead of `std::tr1::shared_ptr`.  Also `unique_ptr` is available.

Comment: I'm coming from C# and I really get mixed messages about shared_ptr.  On the one hand, people say it's really hard to write leak-free code especially when you consider the various exception scenarios, then on the other hand people say don't use it too much.  Although aside from performance disadvantages I'm not too clear on the disadvantages of using smart pointers.

Comment: @User It reduces flexibility as you always have to pass in a `shared_ptr` if the function argument needs one, although it's just not neccessary. Also using a `shared_ptr`-member when there is no ownership semantic (be it just shared ownership), is in the best case conceptually wrong and in the worst case results in plain errors (try not to use smart pointers for not dynamically allocated objects).

Comment: @User Of course smart pointers are often a very good idea, but you just have to be aware of their usage and its implications.

Answer (score 3):

To get this working myService_ and subject needs to be shared_ptr. Otherwise you can try to compare it like this, if subject and shared_ptr points to the same object.

```
  subject == myService_.get()
```

Otherwise try to change all pointers to shared_ptr.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply lets the model inherit from `std::enable_shared_from_this`. If ownership is shared anyways, then `shared_from_this` can be returned from a (possibly virtual) method of the model. Beware, this has some restrictions for the constructor of the model however.